# Relative path in servlet for ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, servlets

I am reading servlet programming . While implementing ServletOutputStream for reading image from relative path it is throwing file not found exception .

I have tried multiple ways but failed , below is the snapshot of relevant code and folder structure in eclipse .

```
    public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        arg1.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        ServletOutputStream out = arg1.getOutputStream();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("images/myimage.jpg");

        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        BufferedOutputStream boit = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        int ch = 0;
        while((ch = bin.read() ) != -1){
            boit.write(ch);
        }
        boit.close();
        bin.close();
        fis.close();
        out.close();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If this is a classpath resource, **do not** use `File` (well, in 2015, don't use `File` at all; use java.nio.file) but the dedicated methods; in your case that would be `.getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Is my relative path wrong ? What changes I have to do for nio. Some more hint/help required @fge

Answer (score 0):

[Get the ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext()). Then [get the resource as a stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

```
final InputStream imageStream = arg0.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/images/myiamge.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks Brett for Answer . After doing changes  , i am getting another error java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)